# The motor barely spins in this H-Bridge circuit?

Tags: raspberry-pi, h-bridge, npn

The motor barely spins in this H-Bridge circuit.

So I put together this schematic with 4x Tip41c NPN transistors.  I also tried tip120 NPN.
The resistors were 1k ohms.
Running off the RaspberryPi 3.3V to the input of this circuit.
The power supply for the motor(vcc was 12V 8 amp hours).  The motor spins fast when hooked up directly to the battery.

[image]

Comment: To test the answers you got, you could use the "Falstad online simulator" to see for yourself what 3v33 does in relation to 12V PSU. you could hook a D-type flip flop (that outputs 3v33, if you set it up right using right click) to the bases of the transistors, using the Q and NOT Q gate while using a clock source input on the clock input of the flip flop and feeding back the NOT Q output back in to the Data input. To get alternating signals for your H bridge. you can see the "current usages" of all wires by double clicking them or assign oscilloscopes to them.

Comment: No wonder! Have you tried to simulate your circuit?

Comment: @NaturalDemon please don't make hobbyist toy recommendations for simulators. This is an engineering site and falsetad falls short of what professional and free simulation software can achieve. If you want to make an answer incorporating a farcetad simulation then that's a different situation.

Comment: _"vcc was 12V 8 amp hours"_ That is a bit odd way of saying you are using an 8 Ah 12 V battery as supply. Vcc is usually reserved for small signal supply and Vbat och Vbus are much more common names for a battery powered system like yours. For future reference, please draw a battery symbol in your schematic and state "12 V 8 Ah" and it would be clear to all readers. EE's have strong emphasis on schematics.

Comment: @Andyaka i recommended the "Falstad simulator" to professor Aaron lanterman and he is using it, it's based on Spice, the guy also has other scientific tools on his site, he is qualified! it works on the basic formulas needed for electronic and not particular models, if you simulate the Moog transistor filter in there, it behave exactly like my psychical DIY soldering experiment in real life, the Falstad simulator does the job perfectly!, it's your personal opinion

Comment: @NaturalDemon of course it's my opinion and, it's your opinion too and, that's why you shouldn't make proposals that someone explicitly uses farsestad (as if it's the only show in town). Clearly it's your favourite but, you'll find that many more engineers use micro-cap or LTspice as freestanding simulation tools with my strong preference being micro-cap (used for 18 years). I have no idea who the person is whom you speak of and, don't see any relevance in attempts at namedropping.

Comment: @Andyaka i got both LTSpice and use Falstad, one is "real time" and the other is not.
Falstad allows you to add "many" oscilloscopes or add multiple signal to one oscilloscope.
In my opinion better than others, because it allows you to use/build with logic gates, like D-type flip flop, counters, AND, NOT, XOR, INV, etc, gates, LATCHES and more, something you can't really do with LTSpice. it's perfect for quick prototyping, it does what's it supposed to do. Make Logic visible. see the calculated consume or voltage per wire if you set it up too. double click the wire or device.

Comment: Adding oscilloscopes is something aimed at the newbie / hobbyist and, it isn't a professional feature no matter how many you can add. I can't speak for LTspice but micro-cap works flawlessly with logic gates and mixed analogue/digital circuits. "Quick prototyping" I assume you mean getting a circuit running quickly and there's nothing slow about micro-cap in this respect and, ditto LTspice when I've used it. Sorry, Farsetad is a toy and, because it doesn't properly model components, it's of no great use to professionals IMHO. In short, Falsetad just doesn't cut the mustard.

Answer (score 3):

There are numerous issues that will come off as you solve them one by one. But the first one is that your high gate drive transistors are emitter followers, not switches.

The emitter on your low side transistors has the emitter fixed to ground and you apply a base voltage relative to ground. But your high side transistors don't have a fixed emitter voltage and since the transistor's conduction depends on the base-emitter voltage difference, as the transistor conducts more, the current flowing through the motor causes a voltage drop across the motor to increase which causes the  emitter voltage to rise and approach the base voltage. Since the base voltage is being applied with respect to ground it does not move. This results in the base-emitter voltage difference getting smaller resulting in negative feedback that prevents the transistor from fully conducting. Instead, it's as a kind of buffer-amplifier that produces an output of ~3.3V at the emitter (since that's what you are applying to the base).

Answer (score 1):

To use a transistor as a switch, the voltage between base an emitter and the driving current define if it will drive it in the cutoff or the saturation.

You are using an all-NPN bridge. For the lower transistors there is no problem (if the driving current is enough) but for the upper transistors you cannot apply the needed voltage unless you add some components like PNP transistor or opto-isolator or other.

There is also a risk to have two transistors of the same side short circuiting the battery (shoot-through) depending on how you manage the dead time.

Comment: `voltage between base an emitter and the driving current` something went awry with this sentence.